# Edit tags not working and comment flag icon missing in Mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-flags, inline-tag-editor

I realise these are 2 separate issues, but I noticed them both at the same time. I can split this into 2 reports if required.

This morning I went to edit a post on my mobile that was tagged incorrectly, I click the edit tags link which brought up an error instead stating:

> An error occurred when fetching the tag editor

I assumed this was a "glitch in the Matrix" and moved on. Since then I've been using the site again in the afternoon, however, I have continued to have the issue, each time I click the edit tags link, I get the error.

Note that I can still edit questions and edit their tags, and I can edit tags on desktop without issue.

At the same time I've noticed that the flag icon next to comments is missing. Again, desktop experience is unaffected.

I can also switch to the desktop view in mobile and can see the icons.

This is also does *not* happen here on meta, just on main; I can edit the tags and flag comments just fine here.

Browser version:

> Firefox 97.1.0 (Build #2015860771), 365e9fb59+.
> AC: 97.0.10, d6ce171289.
> GV: 97.0-20220131171509.
> AS: 87.1.0

Screenshot of failed inline edit and missing flags:

[image]

And Meta looking fine for comparison:

[image]

Comment: This was previously [reported by me on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376339/323179). Does requesting desktop work for you?

Comment: *"I can also switch to the desktop view in mobile and can see the icons."* I didn't check [meta.se] as I don't actually have the issue on MSE, the problem is literally just on [main]. I wonder if that's because I don't have access to the inline editor there, or it's completely unrelated.

Comment: I've been able to reproduce the flag problem on any site by tapping mobile at the bottom (but mobile chrome has a bug so you can't switch back to fix it). You can only reproduce the tag editor problem if you have enough reputation to see it (usually 10k).

Comment: The flagging should be fixed but the inline tag editing is a separate issue - but we're working on it.

Comment: Thanks @Catija , I can confirm I can see flags on comments again.

Comment: This post on [meta.se] is also related: [After clicking the "edit tags" link, a pop-up appears: "An error occurred when fetching the tag editor"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376282)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These should both be fixed now.

From what I understand, we've removed all of the special casing for mobile devices and so there should be generally the same experience on both desktop and mobile view. I tested the inline tag editing on my iPhone in Mobile Safari and it seems to work as expected and the flagging was fixed Feb 17, so I think we're good here.

If you find any outstanding discrepancies after today, please feel free to raise them as a new bug report.